# PHP: array chunk where each chunk is not more than a fixed memory size

Tags: php, arrays, chunks

I have an array

```
$profileIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, .............., 8000];
```

I want to get the minimum number of array chunks like `[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12]` where each chunk size is not more than fixed memory size i.e. 200KB. Thanks in advance.

I am getting the size of the array in bytes by doing:

```
$bytes = mb_strlen(serialize($array), '8bit');
```

Comment: what's your problem? Why doesn't your attempt work? What type of array data is it; woud the single element be bigger than the chunk size?

Comment: What happens if an array element such as the character for `8` crosses the threshold for the chunk size, do you want to split the character itself and leave a mess on each side of the new arrray or?

Comment: @martin, Lets say it is given that a single element will never be bigger than the chunk size.

Comment: You miss my point; if you have elements with a size of 4bits; and you have a chunk size of 14 bits, then you will have potentially 3.5 elements per chunk; so how do you want to handle that half element because that would involve "breaking" the character this represents, and splitting that characters between arrays in your output. It's a mess.

Comment: @Martin I presume chunks need not be of the same size.

Comment: @nice_dev, exactly. But the size shouldn't cross the limit.

Comment: @Md.ZayedHassan Makes sense. How much does `$bytes` give you now?

Comment: @nice_dev, `[1,2,3,4,5]` returns 46 whereas `[1001,1002,1003,1004,1005]` returns 61. I guess that is calculating based on number of characters rather than number of elements.

Comment: @Md.ZayedHassan Not sure of that. It should be worth trying with https://www.php.net/memory_get_usage

Comment: So what is your actual definition of "memory size", the length of the serialized array? If so - _why_? The serialization result is a _textual_ representation of your array data, that has little to do with how much "memory" it will actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`memory_get_usage()`](https://www.php.net/memory_get_usage) seems to do a good job with respect to getting current memory being used by the script. When you are creating a chunk, keep checking with the current memory used with previously recorded memory usage. Difference in both should give you the current memory being used by the chunk.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getChunk($arr, &$idx, $chunkSizeInKB = 200){
  $chunkSize = $chunkSizeInKB * 1000; // in bytes
  
  $memOccupied = memory_get_usage();
  
  $res = [];
  
  for(; $idx < count($arr); ++$idx){
    $res[] = $arr[ $idx ];
    if(memory_get_usage() - $memOccupied > $chunkSize){
      array_pop($res); // because inserting this one made it cross the chunk limit
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return $res;
}

$idx = 0;

$profileIds = range(1, 8000);

while($idx < count($profileIds)){
  echo count(getChunk($profileIds, $idx)),PHP_EOL; // or collect the chunk if you wish
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yf7tczpu)

Answer (score 1):

using `mb_strlen(serialize($array), '8bit')` is the correct way to calculate the array's size (but you will need `memory_get_usage` if you really want to know the total memory used in the script).

The solution will look like this:

```
<?php
$fixmem = 256;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $arrayx[] = $i;
    $bytes = mb_strlen(serialize($arrayx), '8bit');
    if ($bytes > $fixmem) {
        array_pop($arrayx);
        $bytes2 = mb_strlen(serialize($arrayx), '8bit');
        echo "This array's chunk size is $bytes2 bytes.".PHP_EOL;
        print_r($arrayx);
        unset($arrayx);
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```